# Obtener texto de un tag que está tras otro tag

Tags: python, búsquedas, beautifulsoup

Buenas a todos.

Me surge una duda a la hora de parsear un documento html. A la hora de parsear, yo estoy haciendo lo siguiente.

```
browser.get(url+ad) 
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10) 
html_source= browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
```

Para obtener el texto en un tag del tipo que sigue

```
<td><a href="javascript:Team(465)"><font color="green">Palmeiras(N)</font</a></td>
```

Yo estoy haciendo algo como esto

```
soup.find('span').get_text()
>>Palmeiras(N)
```

La cosa es, cuando tengo algo como esto

```
<td><a href="javascript:Team(5156)"><span class="hp">1</span>Atletico Clube Goianiense</a></td>
```

Obtendría

> > 1Atletico Clube Goianiense

Es decir, obtengo no solo el texto que quiero, sino también el texto que hay en este caso en el tag

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera, usando find y find_all de obtener solo el texto que hay dentro del tag  pero fuera del tag ?

En caso de no existir, existe alguna forma con xpath o css de encontrar dicho texto?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vale, he estado buscando por la versión inglesa y creo que he encontrado el como.
Primero buscas el nodo que está inmediatamente anterior a lo que quieres, en este caso 'span', haciendo esto

```
peter=soup.find('span')
```

Luego, utilizas next_sibling para conseguir el texto dentro del tag 'a' pero fuera de 'span'.

```
print(peter.next_sibling)
>>Atletico Clube Goianiense
```

Aun no puedo probarlo porque no tengo mi compilador a mano, pero debería dar la respuesta que estaba buscando.